# Javascript - Esconder filhos do radiobutton quando selecione outro radio do mesmo grupo

Tags: javascript, html, css, input

Tenho um grupo de **Radio Button**, alguns deles tem outros inputs como filhos, se checar o **Input Pai** eles devem aparecer, se for desmarcado eles devem desaparecer.

Como no **HTML** abaixo:

```
<div style="padding-left:30px;clear:both;" class="linha-opcao-resposta">
  <div style="float:left;">
    <label for="7329_2338" title="">27.3 Presença de agentes específicos na citologia oncótica?</label>
    <input type="hidden" title="" id="7329_2338" name="hidden_2338">
  </div>
  <div style="padding-left:30px;clear:both;" class="linha-opcao-resposta">
    <div style="float:left;">
      <input type="radio" title="" id="7330_2370" name="radio_2370"  value="0">
      <label for="7330_2370" title="">Não</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div style="padding-left:30px;clear:both;" class="linha-opcao-resposta">
    <div style="float:left;">
      <input type="radio" title="" id="7331_2370" name="radio_2370"  value="1">
      <label for="7331_2370" title="">Sim </label>
    </div>
    <div style="padding-left: 30px; clear: both; display:none" class="linha-opcao-resposta">
      <div style="float:left;">
        <label for="7331_2371" title="">27.3.1 Agente 1</label>
        <input type="text" title="" id="7331_2371" name="text_2371"  class="rfdRoundedCorners rfdDecorated rfdInputDisabled">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div style="padding-left: 30px; clear: both; display:none" class="linha-opcao-resposta">
      <div style="float:left;">
        <label for="7332_2371" title="">27.3.2 Agente 2</label>
        <input type="text" title="" id="7332_2371" name="text_2371"  class="rfdRoundedCorners rfdDecorated rfdInputDisabled">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div style="padding-left: 30px; clear: both;display:none " class="linha-opcao-resposta">
      <div style="float:left;">
        <label for="7333_2371" title="">27.3.3 Agente 3</label>
        <input type="text" title="" id="7333_2371" name="text_2371"  class="rfdRoundedCorners rfdDecorated rfdInputDisabled">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div style="padding-left:30px;clear:both;" class="linha-opcao-resposta">
    <div style="float:left;">
      <input type="radio" title="" id="7334_2370" name="radio_2370" value="2">
      <label for="7334_2370" title="">Exame não realizado</label>
    </div>
        <div style="padding-left: 30px; clear: both; display:none" class="linha-opcao-resposta">
      <div style="float:left;">
        <label for="7331_2371" title="">27.3.1 Agente 1</label>
        <input type="text" title="" id="7331_2371" name="text_2371"  class="rfdRoundedCorners rfdDecorated rfdInputDisabled">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div style="padding-left: 30px; clear: both; display:none" class="linha-opcao-resposta">
      <div style="float:left;">
        <label for="7332_2371" title="">27.3.2 Agente 2</label>
        <input type="text" title="" id="7332_2371" name="text_2371" class="rfdRoundedCorners rfdDecorated rfdInputDisabled">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div style="padding-left: 30px; clear: both;display:none " class="linha-opcao-resposta">
      <div style="float:left;">
        <label for="7333_2371" title="">27.3.3 Agente 3</label>
        <input type="text" title="" id="7333_2371" name="text_2371" class="rfdRoundedCorners rfdDecorated rfdInputDisabled">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div style="padding-left:30px;clear:both;" class="linha-opcao-resposta">
    <div style="float:left;">
      <input type="radio" title="" id="7405_2370" name="radio_2370" value="3">
      <label for="7405_2370" title="">Não se aplica</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: Correto]

Na imagem **acima** está *correto*, porém se selecionar um input que também tenha filhos, deve fechar todos os outros, assim como abaixo.

[image: Errado]

O mesmo deve acontecer caso selecione um Radio Button que **não** tem filhos, fechar todos os inputs filhos do **grupo**. Assim como na imagem abaixo.

[image: Fechar todos]

Eu fiz esse código mas não tive sucesso...

O problema maior é que deve ser dinâmico, deve funcionar em todos os radiobuttons, por isso usei o evento de click.

```
$('input[type="radio"]').on("change", function() {
  var element = $(this);
  var pais = element
    .parent()
    .parent()
    .parent(); // SUBIR ATÉ A DIV SUPERIOR DO GRUPO
  var filhos = pais.children(".linha-opcao-resposta"); // CAPTURAR AS DIVS FILHAS
  var netos = element
    .parent()
    .parent()
    .children(".linha-opcao-resposta"); // CAPTURAR OS INPUTS FILHOS DO RADIO BUTTON

  if (netos.length > 0) {
    for (let i = 0; i < netos.length; i++) {
      netos[i].style.display = "block";
    }
  } else {
    for (let i = 0; i < filhos.length; i++) {
      netos = filhos[i].children();
      alert(netos.length);
      for (let j = 0; j < netos.length; j++) {
        netos[j].children(".linha-opcao-resposta").style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Começarei recomendando que estude CSS urgentemente. Estilos *inline* são péssimos para dar manutenção, além de deixar o código poluído.

Comment: Eu tenho noção plena do CSS mas na atual situação do código, não tenho condição de aplicar CSS dessa forma... é meio necessário o *inline*, essa aplicação é VB.NET e esse código roda via WebBrowserForm, daí fica um pouco mais complicado eu diria.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**

Como vc falou que tem que ser dinâmico sem precisar usar ID, fiz um modelo com CSS. Tive que mexer pouca coisa no estrutura do HTML, apenas coloquei os campos que vão aparecer dentro da div "pai", assim eu faço uma regra CSS quando o radio:button está :checked

Veja o exemplo como ficou:

```css
input[type="radio"] ~ div {
    display: none;
}
input[type="radio"]:checked ~ div {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div style="padding-left:30px;clear:both;" class="linha-opcao-resposta">
    <div style="float:left;">
        <label for="7329_2338" title="">27.3 Presença de agentes específicos na citologia oncótica?</label>
        <input type="hidden" title="" id="7329_2338" name="hidden_2338">
    </div>
    <div style="padding-left:30px;clear:both;" class="linha-opcao-resposta">
        <div style="float:left;">
            <input type="radio" title="" id="7330_2370" name="radio_2370" value="0">
            <label for="7330_2370" title="">Não</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="padding-left:30px;clear:both;" class="linha-opcao-resposta">
        <div style="float:left;">
            <input type="radio" title="" id="7331_2370" name="radio_2370" value="1">
            <label for="7331_2370" title="">Sim </label>

            <div style="padding-left: 30px; clear: both; " class="linha-opcao-resposta">
                <div style="float:left;">
                    <label for="7331_2371" title="">27.3.1 Agente 1</label>
                    <input type="text" title="" id="7331_2371" name="text_2371" class="rfdRoundedCorners rfdDecorated rfdInputDisabled">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div style="padding-left: 30px; clear: both; " class="linha-opcao-resposta">
                <div style="float:left;">
                    <label for="7332_2371" title="">27.3.2 Agente 2</label>
                    <input type="text" title="" id="7332_2371" name="text_2371" class="rfdRoundedCorners rfdDecorated rfdInputDisabled">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div style="padding-left: 30px; clear: both; " class="linha-opcao-resposta">
                <div style="float:left;">
                    <label for="7333_2371" title="">27.3.3 Agente 3</label>
                    <input type="text" title="" id="7333_2371" name="text_2371" class="rfdRoundedCorners rfdDecorated rfdInputDisabled">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="padding-left:30px;clear:both;" class="linha-opcao-resposta">
        <div style="float:left;">
            <input type="radio" title="" id="7334_2370" name="radio_2370" value="2">
            <label for="7334_2370" title="">Exame não realizado</label>

            <div style="padding-left: 30px; clear: both; " class="linha-opcao-resposta">
                <div style="float:left;">
                    <label for="7331_2371" title="">27.3.1 Agente 1</label>
                    <input type="text" title="" id="7331_2371" name="text_2371" class="rfdRoundedCorners rfdDecorated rfdInputDisabled">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div style="padding-left: 30px; clear: both; " class="linha-opcao-resposta">
                <div style="float:left;">
                    <label for="7332_2371" title="">27.3.2 Agente 2</label>
                    <input type="text" title="" id="7332_2371" name="text_2371" class="rfdRoundedCorners rfdDecorated rfdInputDisabled">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div style="padding-left: 30px; clear: both; " class="linha-opcao-resposta">
                <div style="float:left;">
                    <label for="7333_2371" title="">27.3.3 Agente 3</label>
                    <input type="text" title="" id="7333_2371" name="text_2371" class="rfdRoundedCorners rfdDecorated rfdInputDisabled">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="padding-left:30px;clear:both;" class="linha-opcao-resposta">
        <div style="float:left;">
            <input type="radio" title="" id="7405_2370" name="radio_2370" value="3">
            <label for="7405_2370" title="">Não se aplica</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

*Se vc quiser usar com jQuery*

Cara eu não entendo muito de JS, mas com jQuery fiz esse modelinho bem simples, talvez não seja a melhor forma de escrever o JS, e pode ser que alguém vai saber te responder com um código mais enxuto e que faz a mesma coisa.

Mas aqui tem um exemplo que pode funcionar pra vc, sem precisar de usar ID

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("input[type='radio']").click(function(){
      $('.divOculto')
      .removeClass("show");
      $(this)
      .closest('div')        
      .find('.divOculto')   
      .addClass("show");
   }); 
});
```

```css
.divOculto {
    display: none;
}
.show {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

<div style="padding-left:30px;clear:both;" class="linha-opcao-resposta">
    <div style="float:left;">
        <label for="7329_2338" title="">27.3 Presença de agentes específicos na citologia oncótica?</label>
        <input type="hidden" title="" id="7329_2338" name="hidden_2338">
    </div>
    <div style="padding-left:30px;clear:both;" class="linha-opcao-resposta">
        <div style="float:left;">
            <input type="radio" title="" id="7330_2370" name="radio_2370" value="0">
            <label for="7330_2370" title="">Não</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="padding-left:30px;clear:both;" class="linha-opcao-resposta">
        <div style="float:left;">
            <input type="radio" title="" id="7331_2370" name="radio_2370" value="1">
            <label for="7331_2370" title="">Sim </label>

            <div class="divOculto" style="padding-left: 30px; clear: both; " class="linha-opcao-resposta">
                <div style="float:left;">
                    <label for="7331_2371" title="">27.3.1 Agente 1</label>
                    <input type="text" title="" id="7331_2371" name="text_2371" class="rfdRoundedCorners rfdDecorated rfdInputDisabled">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="divOculto" style="padding-left: 30px; clear: both; " class="linha-opcao-resposta">
                <div style="float:left;">
                    <label for="7332_2371" title="">27.3.2 Agente 2</label>
                    <input type="text" title="" id="7332_2371" name="text_2371" class="rfdRoundedCorners rfdDecorated rfdInputDisabled">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="divOculto" style="padding-left: 30px; clear: both; " class="linha-opcao-resposta">
                <div style="float:left;">
                    <label for="7333_2371" title="">27.3.3 Agente 3</label>
                    <input type="text" title="" id="7333_2371" name="text_2371" class="rfdRoundedCorners rfdDecorated rfdInputDisabled">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="padding-left:30px;clear:both;" class="linha-opcao-resposta">
        <div style="float:left;">
            <input type="radio" title="" id="7334_2370" name="radio_2370" value="2">
            <label for="7334_2370" title="">Exame não realizado</label>

            <div class="divOculto" style="padding-left: 30px; clear: both; " class="linha-opcao-resposta">
                <div style="float:left;">
                    <label for="7331_2371" title="">27.3.1 Agente 1</label>
                    <input type="text" title="" id="7331_2371" name="text_2371" class="rfdRoundedCorners rfdDecorated rfdInputDisabled">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="divOculto" style="padding-left: 30px; clear: both; " class="linha-opcao-resposta">
                <div style="float:left;">
                    <label for="7332_2371" title="">27.3.2 Agente 2</label>
                    <input type="text" title="" id="7332_2371" name="text_2371" class="rfdRoundedCorners rfdDecorated rfdInputDisabled">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="divOculto" style="padding-left: 30px; clear: both; " class="linha-opcao-resposta">
                <div style="float:left;">
                    <label for="7333_2371" title="">27.3.3 Agente 3</label>
                    <input type="text" title="" id="7333_2371" name="text_2371" class="rfdRoundedCorners rfdDecorated rfdInputDisabled">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="padding-left:30px;clear:both;" class="linha-opcao-resposta">
        <div style="float:left;">
            <input type="radio" title="" id="7405_2370" name="radio_2370" value="3">
            <label for="7405_2370" title="">Não se aplica</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ótimo, o problema é que deve ser dinâmico, deve funcionar em todos os radiobuttons da aplicacao, entao nao posso usar id's unicos dessa forma. Eu pensei em fazer um **for** para varrer o grupo

Comment: @CarlitoMurta estou bolando uma forma de fazer com CSS, acho que vai facilitar.

Comment: @CarlitoMurta fiz uma opção só com CSS da uma olhada no **EDIT** que fiz na minha resposta

Comment: Utilizei sua sugestão, voce usou alguma framework ou preprocessador css? nao funcionou pra mim

Comment: @CarlitoMurta não precisa de nenhum processador de CSS, repare que eu tb mudei o HTML como expliquei na resposta. Tive que colocar os inputs que vão aparecer dentro da div pai. Repare que editei novamente a resposta e coloquei uma opção de jQuery bem mais simples, e que não depende de ID para funcionar! Qualquer dúvida fala aqui que tento te explicar. Só o JS que sou meio limitado... mas qq coisa no CSS é só perguntar

Comment: deu tudo certinho depois de modificar o html!, valeu cara, me salvou! e com 7 linhas de CSS hahaha

Comment: @CarlitoMurta boa garoto, boa sorte com o projeto